# Can a simple-page-master inherit another simple-page-master

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I have two master page templates and i'd like them to inherit some common properties from a 3rd master. Can this be done? Below is an example of what i'm attempting.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" page-width="8.5in" 
                         page-height="11in" margin=".5in 1in 0in 1in"/>

  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first" master-reference="page">
    <fo:region-before region-name="header"  extent=".75in"/>
    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom=".75in"/>
    <fo:region-after region-name="footer"  extent=".75in"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>

  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest" master-reference="page">
    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom=".75in"/>
    <fo:region-after region-name="footer"  extent=".75in"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

I'm attempting to inherit the page dimensions from the "page" master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "inherit" like that. A `fo:simple-page-master` element does not take a `master-reference` attribute (and it cannot be empty).

If you use XSLT to generate your XSL-FO, you might want to use *named attribute-sets* (reusable collections of attributes; [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-sets), [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets)).

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately i'm generating my FO programatically using .net